# Strange behavior of networkx draw

Tags: python, networkx

I try to make the simplest graph in networkx:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge('x','y')
```

and that draw it:

```
nx.draw_networkx(G)
```

I have something like this:
[image]
which is absolutely wrong, because I created a graph with only two nodes and one edge between it.

Comment: I used the same code and got an image with two nodes.

Comment: Try `print(G.nodes())` and `print(G.edges())` to make sure you have the correct amount of edges/nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to reproduce a figure that is almost identical to this, but to do so I do the following:

```
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_node('y')
nx.draw_networkx(G)
G.add_edge('x','y')
nx.draw_networkx(G)
```

The first draw command results in `'y'` being at (0,0).  The second draw command generates new coordinates for the nodes, but it does not remove the first drawing of node `'y'`.

I believe this is probably what you actually did.  The code you've provided will behave as you expected it to.